# Adaptec Raid Failed

Tags: raid

i have a Supermicro Server with [this RAID Controller](http://www.supermicro.com.tr/AOC-LPZCR3.cfm.htm). The server works fine, but for cleaning purposes unplug the disks for some time.  After that, the controller shows an error and the server won't boot.

Error:

> fatal error : controller monitor failed. controller not started

[image: Error Message Screen shot]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You **unplugged** working, operational disks from a RAID controller for *cleaning*?!?!

Comment: yes its a old server

Comment: I've never ever heard of anyone ever voluntarily *disconnecting* hard disks from a functional server. That's crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely one of the following:

- The card is not seated correctly. Remove it from the PCIe slot and plug it back in.
- The SAS cables are not connected to the card properly. Try reseating them.
- The card is bad. Try swapping it with a spare.

---

As a side note, you should never remove disks or backplanes from a working server for cleaning. If you're accumulating that much dust in your systems, you should correct your environment so that it's less dusty. Put rules in place like "no cardboard in the server room" and have a proper HVAC system that has clean filters in place.

Comment: thanks, and a bad battery of the raid card can generate the error ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. A bad battery will generate a warning and usually force write-through mode, but should not cause the controller to fail initialization.

Comment: in your opinion the card is dead ?

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: yes, i will try your recommendation, may be the card failed because remove a disk LOL xd